# Computing the number of circles a cell is contained in

Tags: performance, algorithm, geometry

[image: Cell constructed by the circles]

Suppose we have given n cirlces, which construct cells Ci.
The midpoint (x-y coordinates) and radius of every cirlce are given. 
A cell is characterized by its arcs which bound that cell.

For every arc the following informations are given: 
1. The midpoint of the circle it belongs to
2. The source point and target point as x-y coordinate, where the arc starts from and ends.
3. The midpoint of the arc itself is also given with its x-y coordinates.

For Cell1 I have colored the arcs in yellow, blue and brown. Also, I tried to point out the midpoint, target and source of an arc on the picture.

Now, I want to compute the number of circles every cell is contained in with running time O(n²).
For instance, Cell C1 is contained in only 1 circle, Cell C11 in 2 and C5 in 3.

The idea I have computes it in O(m), where as m:= number of arcs.
I think in general the number of arcs can exceed the n².

Any help or idea will be really appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this on a grid? Does each "cell" have an x-y point? Does each given circle have an x-y point for it's center and radius? You could loop through the list of circles and calculate if the x-y point of the cell is inside the space each circle takes on the grid

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I want to compute this"? What is this what you want to compute? (For example if the cell is given just calculate the distance to all the circle centers and you would know in which circles the cell is.)

Comment: Yes, each circle has a midpoint given with their x-y coordinates. The cell do not have any x-y coordinates but the arc of a cell is given by the circle it belongs to, where the origin and the target of the arc is. I would like to compute the number of circles each cell is contained in.

Comment: @Trilarion: I would just like to know the second part: knowing in which cirlces the cell is with running time O(n²).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I think in general the number of arcs can exceed the n².*

Why do you think that?

Any pair of circles intersect in at most two places.  So a single circle will be divided into at most `2n - 2` arcs by the other circles.  Since there are `n` circles, there are at most `2n2 - 2n = O(n2)` arcs.

Comment: I don't understand `2n^2 - 2n = O(n)`. Would that not be O(n^2)?

Comment: @XerXes I did mean to say `O(n²)`.  And I repeat, why do you think it exceeds it?  Particularly given that I just demonstrated that it does not?

Comment: Not sure if you misread who left that comment. I assume the comment to the OP stands but I am not they.

Comment: I think btilly meant O(n²). Your explanation seems reasonable and I will try to proove it by induction. Please correct the minor error in your answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @btilly: Yeah, I wrote that eariler comment thinking I came up with a counter example but found a mistake I made. Awesome, that it does not exceed the n². I was almost sure that it will be O(n³).